# Error running flake8 with new/latest version

Tags: python, pip, pypi, flake8

After installing flake8 and flake8 via pip
pip install flake8 flake8-html
I get following error(was working before, probably caused by new versions of flake8 in recent days):

flake8 --format=html --htmldir=/project/foo/bar/flake8 --exit-zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
...

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/flake8_html/plugin.py", line 281, in write_index
versions=self.option_manager.generate_versions(),

AttributeError: 'OptionManager' object has no attribute 'generate_versions'

Comment: Issue resolved, I used outdated version of Jinja2.

Comment: jinja2 is not involved in that stacktrace